# Having IndentationError: unexpected indent

Tags: python

Im having a indent error in my code and Im not understanding why. Can you see what is wrong here?

If I remove the  `print "hi"` the code works, but if I dont remove I always get this error:

This is the error:

```
print "hi"
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

This is the code:

```
while True:
    while True:
        message = inputqueue.read()
        filename = ""
        if message is not None:
            inputqueue.delete_message(message)
            filename = message.get_body()
            print
            print "Got message %s from queue" % filename

    print "hi"
    s3 = boto.connect_s3()
    bucket_name = "my_folder"
    print "Accessing bucket with name: " + bucket_name
    logging.info("Accessing bucket with name: " + bucket_name)
    bucket = s3.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    key = bucket.get_key(filename)
    to_process_filename = "to_process_" + filename
    key.get_contents_to_filename( to_process_filename )

    print "hi"
```

Comment: The indentation before your second `print "hi"` (the last line) and the blank line above it are with tab characters, everywhere else in the file (that we can see) you use 4 spaces.  Replace the tabs with 4 spaces and you'll be fine.  (Also, correct your editor settings to prevent this in the future :)

Comment: The given code snippet has two instances of `print "hi"`, and no instances of `print "Connecting to EMR"`. Can you clear that up?

Comment: It would give that error if all other lines were indented with tabs and that line was indented with spaces or vice versa. This normally happens if you take existing code and add a line yourself.

Comment: Here is a trollish blog post what could be happening: https://opensourcehacker.com/2012/05/13/never-use-hard-tabs/

Comment: Thanks!! Im a beginner with python and I didnt know that its different indent some lines with space and others with tab, I think that was really the problem, because its working now!

Comment: Tiger, I updated the question, it was with error message print 
print "Connecting to EMR"
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
    ^
and I changed to: IndentationError: unexpected indent to print "hi"
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent.